# Tests for POST request with logged user

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I need to write tests for POST request. The most of them need logged user (sometimes with some permisson). I wrote this test:

```
    <?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\User;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        // $user = new User([
        //     'id' => 1,
        //     'name' => 'yisdfsdsh',
        //     'password' => 'helloWorld',
        //     'admin' => 1
        // ]);
        $user = User::find(1);
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->withHeaders([
            'X-Header' => 'Value',
        ])->json('POST', '/change-password', ['password' => 'newpassword', 'confirmPassword' => 'newpassword']);
        $response->assertStatus(201);

        // $this->get('/')->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

But I have error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

I tryed too:

```
$user = new User([
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'yisdfsdsh',
        'password' => bcrypt('helloWorld'),
        'admin' => 1
    ]);
```

But it receive status 500. How can I wrote this test? This controller's method need to update user's password.

@Edit
I tryed write the code with factory:

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
$response = $this->actingAs($user)->withHeaders([
    'X-Header' => 'Value',
])->json('POST', '/change-password', ['password' => 'newpassword', 'confirmPassword' => 'newpassword']);
$response->assertStatus(201);
```

But i have this same error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

Comment: Are you using a test database like SQLite, for example?

Comment: You should create a User using Factory instead of getting the user with `id = 1` which might not be present in DB.

Comment: I updated my post. I tryed use factory but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to install sqlite sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3 or brew install sqlite3